# IntelliSense in Visual Code doesn't work

Tags: apex, lightning, ide

Started using Visual Code. Downloaded Salesforce Extension Pack. Looks good but IntelliSense doesn't work. Text writer in Trailhead is pretty confident that it should work. Operation system - Mac OS. Visual Code = Version 1.32.1 (1.32.1). Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using SFDX ?

Comment: Do you have Java Development Kit 8 installed, with the `JAVA_HOME` or `JDK_HOME` environment variable pointing to it? See troubleshooting steps here: https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/troubleshooting

Comment: Yes, I have JDK 8 installed and it is SFDX project. Tried instructions from above link and seems this message (which I missed) about java sdk missing disappeared. Thanks. But when I click ^ + space it still doesn't work.

Comment: Found that combination ^+space doesn't work. I changed intellisense action to different shortcut and it works. I don't know why but there is no reference in visual code docs regarding this issue.

Comment: This is old but something you should keep in mind with some of the object intellisense in VSCode with SF development is that you may need to refresh your orgs sObject definitions with the SFDX Power Comands

Comment: @Iaroslav have you managed to resolve this issue? For me IntelliSense doesn't work in apex classes at all. (Windows) It works fine in JS/HTML but not in the apex code. Any suggestions? Sobjects definitions refreshed, but even standard classes like Site, List and so on don't work, infinite loading only..